# How do I update application versioning, are there conventions to follow, are there tools?

Tags: versioning

I do not know why I feel insecure of the things that I am about to do, and I always seek for some advice in the community before doing my move.

Have you used bower and/or npm, they have this cli commands: `bower init` or `npm init` that initiates creation of *bower.json* or *package.json* files respectively. And now it asks me for a version number. FOllowing [semver.org](http://semver.org) tells me that during development 0.y.z is the way to go. Now after doing `npm init`, how do you update the version number? by manually editing the package.json? and doing a commit?

Comment: I've never used them, but IMO, semver.org is good for managing versions. It depends which type of an app you are building, for example, a PHP CMS, or a jQuery plugin (i don't know-never worked with JS)